# Need to compare two rows from the DB in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have the table `users` in laravel.

A user has, among other things, an `id` and an `owner_id`.

I want to perform a query to get all the owners. That means, where the `id` is equal to `owner_id`.

```
Users::where('id','owner_id')->get();
```

Something like this. This didn't work obviously.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `whereColumn` instead.

```
Users::whereColumn('id','owner_id')->get();
```

With `where`, obviously you're just looking for a literal string 'owner_id'.

Comment: Thanks, I thought there was something like this. All the dupes I could find talk about `DB::raw`ing it.

Comment: @ceejayoz Yeah, I probably answered too quickly. This does seem like something that would have a duplicate.

Comment: @Don'tPanic I couldn't find a dupe with the `whereColumn` answer. Next time I see this question I'll know where to go for that. :-D

Comment: @prgrm Yeah, looks like it was added in 5.2. I don't see it in previous versions [in the API](https://laravel.com/api/5.2/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_whereColumn).